# How to make javadoc checker not so strict?

Tags: java, maven, javadoc

I am trying to generate `javadoc` for some not-mine project with `mvn javadoc:javadoc` and getting errors like

```
block element not allowed within inline element <code>: pre
```

and generation fails.

But I don't understand, why `javadoc` should be so strict. Is it possible to make it more tolerant?

Comment: Use the command line option `-Xdoclint:all,-html`

Answer (score 1):

That's a "problem" introduced with Java 8 which has stricter checking (as you noticed). You can set "failOnError" to "false" in the Maven javadoc plugin to workaround it.

It should also be noted that the real solution is to fix the problem. Not to suppress the errors. However I understand that if your just trying to build a project of someone else a quick "fix" is preferable.

Comment: It is very interesting, our team just want it be "strict", due to java 7 dont have this feature, we use jenkins plugin to fail the commit if there is any warnings :)

Comment: @Tim I agree that it is definitely not good practice to just ignore errors. Best solution is to fix the errors instead of suppressing them. Updated the answer to reflect that.